# Cannot log on as other user with Bionic and (vanilla) GNOME without first logging off

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login, login-screen, lock-screen

**NB:** *This* is *not* the same issue as in [this question (Unable to switch users at lock screen. Unity, Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1044779/11316)! In my case `lightdm` isn't even installed and so reinstalling it is not an option.

I am currently still running Bionic (18.04) with `vanilla-gnome-desktop` and [*without* Wayland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578463/5462). All of this happens on the console, i.e. not remotely.

When I lock the desktop, there are two options:

1. to log back in as the user that it already logged (e.g. `user1`)
2. to log in as another user

The screen shows the full name of the user, a field to enter the password, a button "Cancel", a button "Unlock" and a link of sorts "Log in as another user".

(I have no idea how to make a screenshot at that point, so I don't have one)

As long as I am not already logged on as either user or I am logged on and trying to simply unlock the desktop for the logged on user, this works.

However, when I am already logged on as `user1` and now would like to log on as `user2` I'm unable to, after clicking the "Log in as another user" link, I will *very* briefly get a glimpse of the user list and then the screen goes blank. No matter how much I move the mouse or press a key, the only outcome is that after a few seconds I am back to the screen where I need to "slide the screen up" after which I am presented the option to unlock the desktop again (for `user1`, obviously).

In essence this makes it impossible for me to switch between multiple users, which is odd.

Any insights are appreciated. If there is information missing, let me know in the comments and I'll amend the question.

Comment: For your information: lightdm is replaced by gdm - in case you want to reinstall that :)

Comment: @nift4 Sure, I can give that a try. Thanks for the hint. But won't do it before the evening, since I am currently working on said box.

Comment: Just another hint: The package is likely called gdm3 (I forgot that while writing the first comment)

Comment: @nift4 thanks, but I figured that much. And `dpkg -l` or `apt-cache search` would have revealed it as well. But thanks anyway.